# ElementWise resolver must implement broadcast method - Qualcomm SNPE

Tags: tensorflow, qualcomm, snpe

Encountered a problem while trying to run the setup script from Qualcomm SNPE 1.14 to convert a MobileNet_V2 graph into .DLC format.

It passes the ***optimize_for_inference*** stage but fails when running ***convert_to_dlc*** receiving the following error:

`- 123 - ERROR - Conversion failed: ElementWise resolver must implement broadcast method.`

I am guessing this is coming from the residual blocks since the add operations are the only elementwise operations found in Mobilenet_V2 ***expanded_conv*** blocks.

Comment: [Update]: My initial assumption was wrong. Freezed a model without the residual blocks but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error came from using ArgMax, which is not implemented in SNPE.
As a solution, cut ArgMax from the graph, convert your model using SNPE and implement ArgMax in the inference testing code.